# Modifying GRAPE for open quantum systems

Tags: programming, qutip, open-quantum-systems

This question requires the knowledge of [GRAPE](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1090780704003696). More info can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0kgrph09ghy5p74/khaneja2005GRAPE.pdf?dl=0) and in this short [presentation](https://www.dropbox.com/s/huuhqwtvg1bx2ag/grape_june_2010_slides.pdf?dl=0).

I have tried to modify the grape_unitary() function in [grape.py](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/control/grape.py) also to accommodate open quantum systems. One can use it to generate time varying fields for synthesising unitaries for them.
I have tried to run it for the same system as in this [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb).

> I have run into a problem as to some sets of collapse operators give spurious overlap values.

The code seems to work well for the closed system, though it is slower than the original [jupyter notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb). 
Here is the 
[code](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/cag7q460a4macw6/AABxPWkpwQBfDv6pt4R2vNg5a?dl=0)

fsa.py is the file analogous to [grape.py](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/blob/master/qutip/control/grape.py). 
tca.py is the example file (almost entirely based on this [notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb) ) where I run it for a closed quantum system (as in the aforementioned [notebook](https://github.com/qutip/qutip-notebooks/blob/master/examples/control-grape-cnot.ipynb)).
otca.py, otca1.py and other otca*.py are files where I run them for various collapse operators.
tej_plotter.py is just a small python script file to save graphical representation of the final unitaries.

> The explanation of the main idea is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ris74oedclzm7vx/Qutip_open_grape.pdf?dl=0). An updated version will be found [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/bdtqzhgtdkdq)

\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline file & output & collapse\  operator \\ \hline tca.py & copA0 & none \\ \hline otca.py & ocopA0 &  x \otimes y  \\ \hline otca1.py & o1copA0 &  x \otimes y , y \otimes z \\ \hline otca2.py & o2copA0 &  y \otimes z   \\ \hline otca3.py & o3copA0 & z \otimes x \\ \hline otca4.py & o4copA0 &  x \otimes y, z \otimes x \\ \hline otca5.py & o5copA0 &  y \otimes z,  z \otimes x \\ \hline otca6.py & o6copA0 &  x \otimes y , y \otimes z,  z \otimes x \\ \hline  \end{array}
I have also raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/qutip/qutip/issues/1031) on the QuTiP page.

Could this be fixed by redefining (generalising) _overlap(A, B) function in grape.py ?